# Skip column repeats in Postgres select

Tags: postgresql

How can we `SELECT` while skipping column repeats in Postgres?

Here's my table `decisions` below:

| id | trade |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | buy |
| 2 | buy |
| 3 | buy |
| 4 | sell |
| 5 | sell |
| 6 | buy |

I expect to get the following `SELECT` result:

| id | trade |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | buy |
| 4 | sell |
| 6 | buy |

i.e. all records, skipping on repeated `trade` values.

Please do not confuse it with just unique selection.

Comment: window functions?

Comment: @BagusTesa Possibly. An example / answer would be nice though ;)

Comment: its pretty straightforward and someone already answered :) i'm on phone earlier so i cant cook a neatly edited query..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LAG can be used for this, one of the [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```
WITH stats AS (
  SELECT id
       , trade
       , LAG(trade) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS prev_trade
  FROM decisions)
SELECT id, trade
FROM stats
WHERE   prev_trade <> trade
OR      prev_trade IS NULL;
```